# curl command from a linux system to access https://ssl-failure.thousandeyes.net results in an error

Tags: linux

while Using the curl command from a Linux (not a Mac) system to access https://ssl-failure.thousandeyes.net results in an error. However, opening this site in a web browser such as Chrome appears not to generate an error. how is this?

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ssl-failure.thousandeyes.net => "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B." Browsers can sometimes complete a chain using AIA or cache, but curl -- at least builds using OpenSSL or NSS -- does not; maybe MacOS SecureTransport does. Check `curl -V` to confirm what it is using.

Answer (score 0):

From man:

> ```
>   -k/--insecure
>          (SSL)  This  option  explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be made secure by using
>          the CA certificate bundle installed by default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k/--insecure is used.
> ```

You are trying to access a secure(SSL) site use `-k` option to allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.

```
curl -k 'https://ssl-failure.thousandeyes.net/'

<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to ssl-failure.thousandeyes.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome to ssl-failure.thousandeyes.net.  Congratulations, you're reading the secure page</p>
</body>
</html>
```